# Javascript `eval()` scope in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am dynamically creating a function on a `Foo1` instance named `test`. I am creating this function using `eval`. I would expect that this function would have access to the `Foo2` class, however I am getting a `ReferenceError: Foo2 is not defined`.

I have opened up an issue with `Babel` about this and can be be found [here](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7526?workflow=create#R)

If you would like to run the example code yourself, download it from [here](https://github.com/fbgrecojr/foo) and follow the instructions in the `README.MD` to reproduce.

To run:

```
npm install
npm run start
naviage to localhost:8080
```

Here is the directory structure for my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example in my environment:

```
root
  - src
    - Foo1.js
    - Foo2.js
  - .babelrc
  - app.js
  - package.json
```

Foo1.js

```
import Foo2 from './Foo2.js';

export default class Foo1 {
    constructor() {
        // Isolate the impact of eval within makeFunction
        let makeFunction = text => {
            return eval("(function() { " + text + "})");
        };
        this.test = makeFunction('let foo2 = new Foo2(); foo2.test();');
    }
}
```

Foo2.js

```
export default class Foo2 {

    test() {
        console.log('i\'m working!');
    }

}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import Foo1 from './src/Foo1.js';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let test = new Foo1();
    test.test();

    res.end('bye');
});

server.listen(8080);
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js ./app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "http": "*",
        "express": "*",
        "babel-cli": "^6.7.7",
        "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0"
    }
}
```

Now, If I change the `Foo2.js` class to the previous version of javascript everything works like a charm:

```
function Foo2() { }

Foo2.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log('i\'m working!');
};

module.exports = Foo2;
```

Comment: Alright I'm editing the question right now

Comment: Excellent effort on the MCVE, btw.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your code is being encapsulated in a module. Top-level declarations in modules are *not* globals, but as you've discovered, functions created with `new Function` do not close over the context in which they're created; they're created as though they were at global scope.

As you've indicated, `new Function` isn't ideal as it provides for evaluation of arbitrary code, but if ***you* control and can trust** the code you're evaluating, that's not necessarily a problem. The presence of `new Function` also pretty much blows up the JavaScript engine's ability to optimize the code where it appears (since it cannot know what's in the function text), so best to keep these fairly isolated if you can.

Since `new Function` already has both of those problems, we can go ahead and use `eval`, which shares them: `eval` works in the current scope, rather than global scope.

`eval` example:

```js
// Scoping function to fake the effect of module scope
(function() {
    let foo = "bar";

    let algorithm = "console.log(foo);";
    let fn = makeFunction(algorithm);
    fn();

    // Isolate the impact of eval within makeFunction
    function makeFunction(text) {
        return eval("(function() { " + text + "})");
    }
})();
```

Let me reiterate the issues with using `eval`, just to be really clear:

- It's important that you only `eval` code you can **trust**
- Using `eval` in an execution context basically makes it impossible for the JavaScript engine to optimize the code in that context, so keep it isolated to small functions if you can to contain the issue

Comment: Yea I am using ES6 classes here and importing other ES6 classes via modules. How would I then give my functions created with `new Function` the same scope as if I actually typed the function?

Comment: @Frank: The ugly answer is `eval`. :-)

Comment: Since you'd want eval to "Make this a function" rather than just "Do this", I think that for each function you would wrap it in `"function() { <content> }"`

Comment: @Katana314: Yup, inside `(...)` to make it an expression.

Comment: Alright so since `new Function` takes only the function body as it's parameter, I would need to wrap it with `function() { <new Function parameter> }` right @Katana314?. Also, what is the purpose of wrapping it in `'('...')'`?

Comment: @frankgrecojr: That's right. And as I said above, we wrap it in `()` to make it an expression. Otherwise, when the parser sees `function`, it'll assume function *declaration*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hmm I still seem to be running into the same issue. See my edit for what I did/tried.

Comment: @frankgrecojr: What environment are you running this in? The code in those strings absolutely will close over `Ship` and such in the code you've shown.

Comment: Alright so at the top level it is a `Node.js` microservice. A `GET` returns the result of a simulation of 2 `AI's`  being played against each other. There is a separate `Algorithm` microservice that holds the algorithms function bodies and this is where the microservice get's the algorithms from. From there a new instance of a `Simulation` (which is shown in the directory struture above) is created. However, note that if I don't create the functions dynamically and just hard code them in, everything works.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  yep using babel. Everything seems to be working form that aspect.

Comment: @frankgrecojr: The error is revealing: `ReferenceError: Foo2 is not defined at Foo1.eval (eval at makeFunction (Foo1.js:9:16), <anonymous>:1:30)` Note the "at `Foo1.eval`". If eval is being called that way, it's an *indirect* call to `eval`, which won't have access to the current scope (indirect calls to `eval` work at global scope). I think it's a Babel bug. If you do this with NodeJS modules and `require`, the problem doesn't appear. I don't *think* it's a feature of ES2015 modules, I think it's the implementation.

Comment: Yea that would make sense. Looks like I'll have to refactor my code base. I"m going to open up an issue on Babel for this

Comment: Not a bug, Babel just doesn't have any way to support `eval` since we have to rename variables and things to make some features work. Ideally though we'd throw an error or something.

Comment: Damn.  Just came across the same problem.  Are there any workarounds for this issue?  (And @loganfsmyth - I'd say it *is* a bug, even if there isn't any way of solving it; babel claims to support the ES2015 specification, but `eval` isn't behaving the way specified...)  I could dump the symbols my eval code is going to need into global scope by copying them to `window`, but that seems like an ugly hack.  Is there any other way?

Comment: @PeriataBreatta: Not a *bug*, a limitation, just like it can't shim `Proxy`. Logan says there's no way for them to do it. I suspect that's not quite literally true (they could have the transpiled code include a map of all renamed symbols [even in production] and include the JS version of Babel [even in production] and replace `eval` with something accepting the runtime string and running it through the JS version of Babel feeding in the map of renamed symbols; then eval the result in context), but it seems hard to justify the effort for an edge case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work is because you use babel to transform your code, which changes the `import Foo2` and all references to `Foo2` into some object property access. But it can not change your eval'd code as that is only known at run-time and not build time, so there your Foo2 remains unchanged and invalid.